# Is there any way to recover my past questions?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, soft-question

First of all, it is completely my fault that I hadn't registered and kept posting questions, and I'm not sure which should this post be tagged..

I just have noticed that all my information is gone and I cannot find my previous questions. (As you can see in my info page, it says I'm a member for *today*..)

Is there anyway to recover my precious questions..?

Comment: @Katlus Partial solution: go to www.google.com and search for exact sequences of words which were in your question inbetween " ". Check my answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273374/need-help-finding-a-blog-post/273379#273379 for more details.

Comment: You’ll get pretty good results if you do a Google search on $$\text{katlus site:math.stackexchange.com}$$

Comment: @Brian Best! Thank you

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: So: 1) [register your current account](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/login). 2) merge it with the [old account](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/29511/katlus) by following [these instructions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: @Martin: Does the new self-service merging work if the accounts to merge are unregistered and so cannot be logged in to? (Unregistered account identity depends on cookies, and therefore disappears if one logs into a registered accound, doesn't it?)

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I don't know. The instructions end with: "If you have lost access to your duplicate account, please click here to fill out the form." and "If your issue was not covered above, please feel free to contact us directly.", so it seems that this case is covered as well.